# Object Still Null even after Check

Tags: android, arrays, json

I check to make sure that the object is not Null before I set it but it still returns Null.

Code:

```
JSONObject json = jparse.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                JSONObject c;
                JSONObject d;
                try {
                    pictures = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PICTURES);
                    c = pictures.getJSONObject(2);
                    gallery = c.getJSONArray(TAG_GALLERY);
                    Log.d(tag, "after pictures");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    //get every instance of thumbPath here
                    //looping through all of Gallery  
                    for(int z = 0; z < gallery.length(); z++){
                        thumbpaths = new String[gallery.length()];
                        captions = new String[gallery.length()];
                        d = gallery.getJSONObject(z);
                        String thumbpath = d.getString(TAG_THUMBPATHS);
                        String Captions = d.getString(TAG_CAPTIONS);
                        Log.d(tag, "Captions:" + Captions);
                        Log.d(tag, "Path:" + thumbpath);
                        if(thumbpath != null && Captions != null){
                        thumbpaths[z] = thumbpath;
                        captions[z] = Captions;
                        }else{
                            Log.d(tag, "thumbpath or Caption null");
                        }
                    }  
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(thumbpaths != null){
                    for(int i = 0; i < thumbpaths.length; i++){
                    Log.d(tag,"thumbPaths:" + thumbpaths[i]);
                    }
                bitmaps = getImagesFromPaths(thumbpaths);
                }
```

You can see with the above I am parsing a JSON object and getting a list of paths from it. These paths need to be passed to `getImagesFromPaths(paths)` it never reaches that and crashes application because its returning null on everything but the last path.

I check with `if(thumbpath != null && Captions != null)` before setting it to the array, I don't see why it would still place it and not move to my log.

How can I get this to have all the paths so I can send them to get received from the URL?

Comment: would you mind posting the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have added a comment but I don't have the reputation.

A problem I noticed:

This...

```
for(int z = 0; z < gallery.length(); z++) {

    thumbpaths = new String[gallery.length()];
    captions = new String[gallery.length()];

    ...
}
```

Should be...

```
thumbpaths = new String[gallery.length()];
captions = new String[gallery.length()];

for(int z = 0; z < gallery.length(); z++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I gave it to you because you answered first, but you and iahsrah where right. I must have simply looked over that. I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You do realise that your thumbpaths and captions arrays are intialized to their size with full of null values right?  so if you were to not set an index (z) with non-null values, they would still be null.   You are doing this at every loop iteration!

```
// All values in the array have been initialized to null
thumbpaths = new String[gallery.length()];
captions = new String[gallery.length()];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(thumbpath != null && Captions != null)
```

You are checking both for null together. Your statement is saying that they both cannot equal null, perhaps `Captions` aren't null, but `thumbpath` is (or vice versa [not likely]), your statement will still be true.

You need to check separately:

```
if(thumbpath != null) {
    if (Captions != null){
         thumbpaths[z] = thumbpath;
         captions[z] = Captions;
    }
} else { /* Do other stuff... */ }
```

EDIT: Also, as @Iahsrah said, you're reinitializing both of your arrays to null every iteration of your for loop, that is why only the last contains any non-null value (it didn't have an opportunity to be initialized over).

You need to put these outside your for loop:

```
thumbpaths = new String[gallery.length()];
captions = new String[gallery.length()];
```